# Sort PHP foreach loop lowest to highest

Tags: php

I have a PHP foreach loop that displays the lowest possible rate on each users profile. How can I sort the foreach loop to display profiles from lowest to highest rate without changing the SQL statement?

```
$results = DB::query('SELECT users.`id`, rates.`basic`, rates.`standard`, rates.`premium` FROM rates, users WHERE rates.`rate_id` = users.`id`');

foreach($results as $row){
  if($row['basic'] !=""){
     $minrate = $row['basic'];
  }elseif($row['standard'] !=""){
     $minrate = $row['standard'];
  }elseif($row['premium'] !=""){
      $minrate = $row['premium']; 
  }
  <?php echo $minrate ?>
}
```

Comment: Just apply an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query! Why don't you want to do that? Otherwise you're going to have to read all the results into a PHP array and then sort that array

Comment: add  a proper data sample the related  table schema and the exptected  result

Answer (score 2):

The ideal solution for this is to use `SQL` on sorting results. But if for a certain reason, you cant alter the `SQL` code. You can:

```
    $tempArr = array();
    foreach($results as $row){
        if($row['basic'] != ""){
             $minrate = $row['basic'];
        }elseif($row['standard'] !=""){
             $minrate = $row['standard'];
        }elseif($row['premium'] !=""){
              $minrate = $row['premium']; 
        }

        //Make the $minrate the key - Will be easy to sort | Make a multi dimensional array, incase duplicate on $minrate
        if ( !isset( $tempArr[ $minrate ] ) ) $tempArr[ $minrate ] = array();
        $tempArr[ $minrate ][] = $row;
    }

    //Sort an array by key
    ksort( $tempArr );

    //Make Multi dementional array to single array
    $sortedResult = array();
    foreach( $tempArr as $tempArr2 ) {
        foreach( $tempArr2 as $value ) {
            $sortedResult[] = $value;
        }
    }

    //$sortedResult <-- As the variable says, It should be sorted
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $sortedResult ) ;
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

seems you have  bad data strucs Instead of a relation between user and the user rate you have a relation between user a set of columns for different possible rate

then you could use case when  for filter (and normalize) the set of columns
and you could obtain the ordered result directly form SQL

```
   SELECT 
    users.id, 
      case when  rates.basic is not null then 0
           when  rates.standard is not null then 1
           when  rates.premium is not null then 2 
          end as my_rate,
      case when  rates.basic is not null then 'BASIC'
           when  rates.standard is not null then  'STANDARD'
           when  rates.premium is not null then  'PREMIUM'
          end as my_rate_text    
      FROM rates, users WHERE rates.`rate_id` = users.`id`
      ORDER BY  my_rate
      ;
```